# Implicit Euler Scheme

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

The evolution equation is given by

$$u_t=u-u^2+u_{xx}$$

on interval $[0,10]$ with the initial condition:

$$u(x,0)=\frac{t}{5}-1$$

I want the form for fully implicit Euler scheme to generate approximate values of $u(x,t)$.

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Your equation is nonlinear and discretising nonlinear terms _implicitly_ leads to a set of nonlinear algebraic equations. So you'll find a fully implicit approach rather difficult here.

Comment: @mattos can you be a bit more specific please. I am not familiar with these jargons.

Comment: You're going to have to do some reading then, because it will be too long for me to explain. Can you provide some context to your question? i.e Is this a homework/assignent question? Or is this just something you want to implement yourself? Once I know this I might be able to provide some help.

Comment: @mattos 
I am preparing for my exams and this is a question that appeared in past exam. My problem won't end here, for I have to implement it by Python as well. A better understanding of it will help me prepare well.

Answer (score 0):

For the Euler step you have to solve 
$$
u(x,t-h)=u(t,x)-h\Bigl(u(x,t)-u(x,t)^2+u_{xx}(x,t)\Bigr)
$$ 
as an ODE with boundary conditions for the function $[x\mapsto u(x,t)]$ for fixed $t$ and $h$.

Usually one works with a fixed discretization in $x$ direction, so that this BVP transforms into a collection of coupled quadratic equations. You can also try shooting or multiple shooting using $u(x,t-h)$ to initialize it, as $u(x,t)$ should only have a distance $O(h)$ from it.